# Not able to interpolate

Tags: javascript, apostrophe, template-literals, template-strings

I'm currently doing the codecademy introduction to javascript.

```
const takeOrder = (topping) => {
  console.log('Order: pizza topped with ${topping}');
};

takeOrder("mushrooms");
```

shouldn't this work too instead of

```
const takeOrder = (topping) => {
  console.log('Order: pizza topped with' +topping);
};

takeOrder("mushrooms");
```

I am not sure why I can not interpolate like this?

Comment: For template literal you need to use `\`` instead of `'`

Comment: Because interpolated strings use a different delimiter.

Comment: Be careful when taking mushrooms.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thanks

Answer (score 0):

`console.log('Order: pizza topped with ${topping}');`

> shouldn't this work too

No. You want backticks to use string template literals

```
const takeOrder = (topping) => {
  console.log(`Order: pizza topped with ${topping}`); //NB `
};

takeOrder("mushrooms");
```